# can't log in after changing network from domain to workgroup

Tags: login-screen

I really pulled a stupid.  Now I can't log in to my computer.  I've heard that you need to create a boot disk and override the admin password, but I'm not sure what to do?  I'm can't get past the login screen and I'm stuck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [UBCD](http://www.ubcd4win.com/) to [reset](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/reset-your-forgotten-password-the-easy-way-using-the-ultimate-boot-cd-for-windows/) the local admin password, then log in and add myself back to the domain.